# I face a problem in C. Input is wrong-- its say Segmentation fault

Tags: c, structure

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student_details{
    char name[34];
    int roll;
    char section;
};

int main(){
    struct student_details student[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("Your full name = ");
        scanf("%s", student[i].name);
        printf("Your roll = ");
        scanf("%d", student[i].roll);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I think something is wrong with my code anyone please fix this.
When I run this code, it's Shows an error. after running this code this code take 1 time input and second input is skipped.

[image: Check this Image]

Comment: `scanf("%d", &student[i].roll);` Note the `&`, it means you have to pass the address of the variable in which you would like to store the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scanf` function expects to accept a format string and then pointers to the data you want to scan into.  `student[i].name` is an array, which in this case decays into a pointer to its first element. This works.

***Note:** This array only contains 34 characters. With the null terminator, you want to use a width specifier with `scanf` to limit the input and prevent a buffer overflow. `"%33s"`*

When you try to read the `roll`:

```
scanf("%d", student[i].roll);
```

`student[i].roll` is an int, not a pointer. But pointers *are* numbers, so this will compile. Your compiler should warn you about it, though. But, then the program tries to dereference this value it thinks is a pointer, and a segmentation fault occurs.

What you want to do is pass the *address* of `student[i].roll`.

```
scanf("%d", &student[i].roll);
```